# Notes Application terminating on every startup

Tags: macos, notes.app

I have been a heavy-user of the build in Notes Application on OS X for a couple of months now. I am running Yosemite 10.10.4. But suddenly the App crashed on every startup. This is the error message I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'Got more than one folder with folderId AQMkADllODE4Yzg1LTM3MjktNGVlAGEtODRkZi1jZDdmMGViMWVjYjcALgAAA2uk2E33q9BMt5S6XXxtY3cBADMZ7DRFZNJAkM1D4wHoODQAAAMKAAAA'
    abort() called
    terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

As it is a build in App I can't simply reinstall it. Any advice on what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution: I had two Exchange Accounts connected and synchronised the notes from them. After removing them through the settings Notes is working again :)